# how to execute JOIN query with 3 tables, order by count of ID

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 3 tables:
    **Event, EventSeans, Firms**.
I need to return Firm, and order by count Event in this Firm
Event entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="EventSeans",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"},
 *    mappedBy="event"
 *  )
 *  @ORM\OrderBy({"start_time"= "ASC"})
 */
protected $seanses;
```

EventSeans entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity="Application\GidBundle\Entity\Firm")
 */
protected $place;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity="Event",
 *      inversedBy="seanses"
 * )* 
 */
protected $event;
```

I tried this:

```
        $qb
        ->select('f, count(e.id) cnt')
        ->from('AfishaBundle:Event', 'e')
        ->from('GidBundle:Firm', 'f')
        ->leftJoin('e.seanses', 's')
        ->where('s.place = f.id')
        ->orderBy('cnt','ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(3)
    ;
```

**EDIT**
i add relation in Firm Entity

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="Application\AfishaBundle\Entity\EventSeans",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"},
 *    mappedBy="place"
 *  )
 *  @ORM\OrderBy({"start_time"= "ASC"})
 */
protected $seanses;
```

and my query is

```
        $qb
        ->select('f, count(e.id) cnt')
        ->from('GidBundle:Firm', 'f')
        ->leftJoin('f.seanses','s')
        ->leftJoin('s.event', 'e')
        ->orderBy('cnt', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('f.id')
        ->setMaxResults(20)
    ;
```

But cnt - is a count of my seanses... It's nothing changes:(

**add**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `afisha_event_seanses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `place_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `allday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hall` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_3164A4B7DA6A219` (`place_id`),
  KEY `IDX_3164A4B771F7E88B` (`event_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

 ALTER TABLE `afisha_event_seanses`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_3164A4B771F7E88B` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `afisha_events` (`id`),
   ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_3164A4B7DA6A219` FOREIGN KEY (`place_id`) REFERENCES `gid_firms` (`id`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I suppose your entity relationships are well defined.

The following code should return Firms with count of Events related to each Firm.

Add a method in your **FirmRepository** which contain,

```
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
           ->select(' f, count(distinct e.id)')
           ->leftJoin('f.seanses', 's')
           ->leftJoin('s.event', 'e')
           ->groupBy('f.id')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getArrayResult();
```

Where `event` define a many-to-one relationship from your `EventSeans` Entity to your `Event` Entity as follow,

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\GidBundle\Entity\Event")
 */
protected $event;
```

Comment: The Firm entity has no 'seanses' field.
Symfony says "Class Application\GidBundle\Entity\Firm has no association named seanses"

Comment: I`m tried this, but count return the count of seanses


    $qb
                ->select('f , count(e.id)')
                ->from('GidBundle:Firm', 'f')
                ->from('AfishaBundle:Event', 'e')
                ->leftJoin('e.seanses','s')
                ->where('s.place = f.id')
                ->groupBy('f.id')
            ;

Comment: I think I don't quite understand you :( 
i has updated my post with all relationship between EventSeans(), Event and Firm

Comment: From you question, I understand that both Firm and Event entities had seanses attribute! review your question.

Comment: no.Only Event has seanses attribute.
Each Event has many EventSeanses. Each EventSeans has many Firm.
But between Firm and EventSeanses has no relationship.

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint of place and event for your EventSeans? I used your relations definition and I get firms with the count of all their related events.

Comment: what do you mean when you said "unique constraint of place and event for your EventSeans"? Many seanses have firm and event, it can not be a uniquie, i guess
I has update post,add Full dump my EventSeans table

Comment: Put another way, my question is, can you have many relations EventSeans between a specific Event and a specific Firm?
If it's the case, You want to count all these relations between two specific entities as One because only one Event is concerned, right?

Comment: Ok, I got the problem, just replace your "count(e.id) cnt" with "count(distinct e.id)". I updated my answer.